# Интонационное тире

Tags: пунктуация, тире, интонация

> Желание стать чьим-то спутником () превратилось в слезу в твоих руках.
>
> Они умеют () что сказать.

Здесь тире уместно только как интонационное?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В первом предложении никакой знак не нужен, там есть естественная пауза между составом подлежащего и составом сказуемого. Второе предложение неясно.

Comment: Поясню второе.Разговорный стиль.

Ну что(тут)сказать()они это умеют.

Comment: Думаю, более уместны запятая или двоеточие: Ну что(тут)сказать,они это умеют.(Сказать здесь нечего, только то, что они это умеют). Ну что(тут)сказать: они это умеют.(Сказать здесь нечего, (почему?)-потому что они это умеют ). Причинно-следственные связи можно оформить и как тире:Ну что(тут)сказать -они это умеют, но это будет уже авторское тире.

Comment: Ну что тут еще можно сказать(добавить)()они это умеют. 
Они умеют()что сказать.

Можно и так трактовать.Но это не означает,что сказать нечего.
В этом случае лучше поставить двоеточие? В обоих вариантах?

Answer (score 2):

"Они умеют()что сказать".

Возможно, автор заменил невыразительное "знают" на авторское "умеют". Смысл таков: (1) они правильно подбирают нужные слова. Тогда классическая форма "они знают, что сказать" может перейти в "они умеют что сказать", где использован более уместный устойчивый оборот. Тогда никакого знака не нужно.

Если нет контекста, то можно предположить другой смысл: (2) они умеют это делать - что тут говорить. Но заданная форма этот смысл передать не может - ее надо корректировать.

Поэтому можно пожелать автору текста работать не только над выразительностью формы, но и над ее однозначностью и правильностью.

Comment: Они умеют это делать - что тут говорить. - Этот вариант.Вы правы.

Они умеют()что сказать.  - Разве так нельзя написать?И возможно ли тире в такой форме?

Comment: Думаю, что единственный вариант для этой фразы - это отсутствие всякого знака. Так вы можете обозначить ее условность, применить особый художественный прием. Форма для этого хорошо известна: "делай что хочешь", "поступай как знаешь" - это устойчивые обороты речи в роли  обстоятельства. 
И давайте обсудим интонацию. При отсутствии запятой нет паузы между словами. Тире - это подчеркнутая пауза, запятая - небольшая пауза, обозначающая деление предложения на две части.И знаки, и паузы приводят к тому, что  неоднозначно определяется как содержание предложения, так и и его оформление.

Answer (score 0):

Желание стать чьим-то спутником()превратилось в слезу в твоих руках.

Они умеют()что сказать. В первых скобках тире неуместно вообще. Во вторых - нужна запятая. Но оба предложения логически и стилистически неряшливы: слезу в руках не держат (правильнее было бы сказать: "обернулось для тебя слезами"). Во втором предложении уместен глагол "знают" вместо "умеют".

Comment: Они умеют(могут) что-то сделать хорошо,что тут еще можно сказать(добавить нечего). 
Такой контекст.
Они знают,как что-то сделать хорошо.Вы это подразумеваете?